# DB2 query to find average sale for each item 1 year previous

Tags: sql, db2

Having some trouble figuring out how to make these query.

In general I have a table with

- sales_ID
- Employee_ID
- sale_date
- sale_price

what I want to do is have a view that shows for each sales item how much the employee on average sells for 1 year previous of the sale_date.

example: Suppose I have this in the sales table

```
sales_ID    employee_id    sale_date    sale_price
1           Bob            2016/06/10    100
2           Bob            2016/01/01    75
3           Bob            2014/01/01    475
4           Bob            2015/12/01    100
5           Bob            2016/05/01    200
6           Fred           2016/01/01    30
7           Fred           2015/05/01    50
```

for sales_id 1 record I want to pull all sales from Bob by 1 year up to the month of the sale (so 2015-05-01 to 2016-05-31 which has 3 sales for 75, 100, 200) so the final output would be

```
sales_ID    employee_id    sale_date    sale_price    avg_sale
1           Bob            2016/06/10    100          125
2           Bob            2016/01/01    75           275
3           Bob            2014/01/01    475          null
4           Bob            2015/12/01    100          475
5           Bob            2016/05/01    200          87.5
6           Fred           2016/01/01    30           50
7           Fred           2015/05/01    50           null
```

What I tried doing is something like this

```
select a.sales_ID, a.sale_price, a.employee_ID, a.sale_date, b.avg_price
from sales a
left join (
     select employee_id, avg(sale_price) as avg_price
     from sales 
     where sale_date between Date(VARCHAR(YEAR(a.sale_date)-1) ||'-'|| VARCHAR(MONTH(a.sale_date)-1) || '-01')
                  and Date(VARCHAR(YEAR(a.sale_date)) ||'-'|| VARCHAR(MONTH(a.sale_date)) || '-01') -1 day
    group by employee_id
) b on a.employee_id = b.employee_id
```

which DB2 doesn't like using the parent table a in the sub query, but I can't think of how to properly write this query. any thoughts?

Comment: (1) What is the issue in the given query. Do you get any error? Does the inner query run properly on its own?
(2) Can you give some sample data and expected output?

Comment: doesn't recognize a.sale_date error
SQLCODE = -204 and SQLSTATE=42704
will edit question with an example

Comment: It is still confusing. The `3` sales for `Bob` have a different `sales_id`? What should be the output of those? Please give an example of atleast 2 employees with different sales and your expected output on all of the rows for that.

Comment: No, I don't know how to write the where clause right that it looks for only items that are just 1 year previous of the sales item in the row.

Comment: For `sales_id`=`2`, how is average sale `275`. Can you explain the maths for it?

Comment: and also how is average 475 for sales_id=4??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I think I figured it out. Please note 3 things.

1. I couldn't test it in DB2, so I used Oracle. But syntax would be more or less same.
2. I didn't use your 1 year logic exactly. I am counting current_date minus 365 days, but you can change the `between` part in `where` clause in inner query, as you mentioned in the question.
3. The expected output you mentioned is incorrect. So for every `sale_id`, I took the date, found the `employee_id`, took all the sales of that employee for last 1 year, excluding the current date, and then took average. If you want to change it, you can change the where clause in subquery.

   ```
   select t1.*,t2.avg_sale 
   from 
   sales t1
   left join 
   (
       select a.sales_id
       ,avg(b.sale_price) as avg_sale
       from sales a
           inner join 
       sales b
        on a.employee_id=b.employee_id
           where b.sale_date between  a.sale_date - 365 and  a.sale_date -1
       group by a.sales_id
   ) t2
   on t1.sales_id=t2.sales_id
   order by t1.sales_id
   ```

Output

```
+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+----------+
| SALES_ID | EMPLOYEE_ID |  SALE_DATE  | SALE_PRICE | AVG_SALE |
+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+----------+
|        1 | Bob         | 10-JUN-2016 |        100 | 125      |
|        2 | Bob         | 01-JAN-2016 |         75 | 100      |
|        3 | Bob         | 01-JAN-2014 |        475 |          |
|        4 | Bob         | 01-DEC-2015 |        100 |          |
|        5 | Bob         | 01-MAY-2016 |        200 | 87.5     |
|        6 | Fred        | 01-JAN-2016 |         30 | 50       |
|        7 | Fred        | 01-MAY-2015 |         50 |          |
+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can almost fix your original query by doing a `LATERAL` join. Lateral allows you to reference previously declared tables as in:

```
select a.sales_ID, a.sale_price, a.employee_ID, a.sale_date, b.avg_price
from sales a
left join LATERAL (
     select employee_id, avg(sale_price) as avg_price
     from sales 
     where sale_date between Date(VARCHAR(YEAR(a.sale_date)-1) ||'-'|| VARCHAR(MONTH(a.sale_date)-1) || '-01')
                  and Date(VARCHAR(YEAR(a.sale_date)) ||'-'|| VARCHAR(MONTH(a.sale_date)) || '-01') -1 day
    group by employee_id
) b on a.employee_id = b.employee_id
```

However, I get an syntax error from your date arithmetic, so using @Utsav solution for this yields:

```
select a.sales_ID, a.sale_price, a.employee_ID, a.sale_date, b.avg_price
from sales a
left join lateral (
    select employee_id, avg(sale_price) as avg_price
    from sales b
    where a.employee_id = b.employee_id 
     and b.sale_date between  a.sale_date - 365 and a.sale_date -1
    group by employee_id
) b on a.employee_id = b.employee_id
```

Since we already pushed the predicate inside the `LATERAL` join, it is strictly speaking not necessary to use the on clause:

```
select a.sales_ID, a.sale_price, a.employee_ID, a.sale_date, b.avg_price
from sales a
left join lateral (
    select employee_id, avg(sale_price) as avg_price
    from sales b
    where a.employee_id = b.employee_id 
     and b.sale_date between  a.sale_date - 365 and a.sale_date -1
    group by employee_id
) b on 1=1
```

By using a `LATERAL` join we removed one access against the sales table. A comparison of the plans show:

### *No LATERAL Join*

Access Plan:

```
        Total Cost:             20,4571
        Query Degree:           1

            Rows 
           RETURN
           (   1)
            Cost 
             I/O 
             |
              7 
           >MSJOIN
           (   2)
           20,4565 
              3 
         /---+----\
        7        0,388889 
     TBSCAN       FILTER
     (   3)       (   6)
     6,81572      13,6402 
        1            2 
       |            |
        7         2,72222 
     SORT         GRPBY 
     (   4)       (   7)
     6,81552      13,6397 
        1            2 
       |            |
        7         2,72222 
     TBSCAN       TBSCAN
     (   5)       (   8)
     6,81488      13,6395 
        1            2 
       |            |
        7         2,72222 
 TABLE: LELLE     SORT  
      SALES       (   9)
       Q6         13,6391 
                     2 
                    |
                  2,72222 
                  HSJOIN
                  (  10)
                  13,6385 
                     2 
              /-----+------\
             7                7 
          TBSCAN           TBSCAN
          (  11)           (  12)
          6,81488          6,81488 
             1                1 
            |                |
             7                7 
      TABLE: LELLE     TABLE: LELLE   
           SALES            SALES
            Q2               Q1
```

### LATERAL Join

Access Plan:

```
    Total Cost:         13,6565
    Query Degree:       1

            Rows
           RETURN
           (   1)
            Cost
             I/O
             |
              7
          >^NLJOIN
          (   2)
           13,6559
              2
         /---+----\
        7          0,35
     TBSCAN       GRPBY
     (   3)       (   4)
     6,81488      6,81662
        1            1
       |            |
        7          0,35
 TABLE: LELLE     TBSCAN
      SALES       (   5)
       Q5         6,81656
                     1
                    |
                     7
              TABLE: LELLE
                   SALES
                    Q1
```

### Window functions with framing

DB2 does not yet support range frames over dates, but by using a clever trick by @mustaccio in:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141263/what-is-the-meaning-of-order-by-x-range-between-n-preceding-if-x-is-a-dat

we can actually use only one table access and solve the problem:

```
select a.sales_ID, a.sale_price, a.employee_ID, a.sale_date
     , avg(sale_price) over (partition by employee_id 
                             order by julian_day(a.sale_date) 
                             range between 365 preceding
                                       and 1 preceding
                            ) as avg_price 
from sales a
```

Access Plan:

```
    Total Cost:             6.8197
    Query Degree:           1

      Rows 
     RETURN
     (   1)
      Cost 
       I/O 
       |
        7 
     TBSCAN
     (   2)
     6.81753 
        1 
       |
        7 
     SORT  
     (   3)
     6.81703 
        1 
       |
        7 
     TBSCAN
     (   4)
     6.81488 
        1 
       |
        7 
 TABLE: LELLE   
      SALES
       Q1
```